# Customize Build Summary TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I do know that it is possible to customize the Build summary of a TFS 2010 build. But so far I was not able to get good infos how to do it. Does anybody know of good resources to customize a VS2010 Build Summary page. The summary rendering is done via a dll which must be deployed on every developers machine. This is not nice but if there is no better solution available I am willing to take this route.

I am not talking about the Web URL which from where I can view the build output in the browser as well if (as always) the output gets huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mentioned how to create a build summary report section on Page 424 (Chapter 16) of our book:  [Professional Team Foundation Server 2010](http://bit.ly/TFS2010Book) by Wrox.  Here's a blog post by Jason Prickett that talks all about it:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/08/09/tfs2010-customizing-the-build-details-view-summary-view.aspx

[image: Custom Build Log Summary Section for TFS]

You are right though that those customizations need to be deployed to all client machines.  You could potentially deploy them as a VSIX package internally though if you wanted to simplify the deployment & updates.